# Swift: How to typecast an AnyObject to an NSArray in this situation?

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-errors

The compiler tells me that AnyObject? does not have a member named 'count'.For the following code. I am wondering if there is a way to type cast it as an NSArray?

```
        if  answer.objectForKey("answer").count == 0  {

         }
```

I tried `answer.objectForKey("answer").count == 0 as NSArray` ,but I get the same exact compiler error.

Edit:    `let answer : AnyObject = answerArray.objectForKey(key)!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would be to use a checking cast:

```
if let contents = answer.objectForKey("answer") as? NSArray {
    if contents.count == 0 {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like this would be:

```
(answer.objectForKey("answer") as NSArray?).count
```